# drag and drop of items in listview in android?

Tags: android

i have a listview with n number of list items. I want to implement drag and drop of items from one position to antother position in the list android?

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html (works only from API 11 onwards)

Comment: i want an example how can we implement drag and drop of items in the list view

Comment: [Here](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/10/experience-android-drag-and-drop-list.html) You can find best Tutorial for Drag N Drop...

Comment: Refer to this [link](https://github.com/mtparet/Drag-And-Drop-Android).

Answer (score 4):

Another implementation:

- https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview

Comment: This is a very good app and a very complete example, but very complicated to people that want to start for some basic examples.

Answer (score 3):

Here is our drag & drop list. Tt is a direct replacement for ListView and it's very easy to use.

https://github.com/terlici/DragNDropList

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I did read it. I had the same problem as in this and many other similar questions. I made a simple solution for me and I hope that it can solve this problem for others, too.

Comment: Thank you!  The best by far IMHO after wasting a lot of time trying others.

Answer (score 3):

In August 2013 **Google** uploaded a very simple example with a video and the code.

Video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BZIvjMgH-Q
code: http://developer.android.com/shareables/devbytes/ListViewDraggingAnimation.zip

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you want a complete example for the [`Drag and Drop ListView`](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/10/experience-android-drag-and-drop-list.html). Download it, built it and Enjoy!!!!!